# Free app and License Version Check

Tags: android

I have a free version app and a paid version for it.
The paid version simply unlock the functionalities of the free app.

The paid app use the Application Licensing. 
How can I to check the license by free version?
Did you have the same problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to understand what do you need. The free version will be always licensed by definition. Verbatim from the Dev Guide (emphasis mine):

> Application, Android Market client,
>   and server
>
> The licensing service is based on the
>   capability of the Android Market
>   server to determine whether a given
>   user is licensed to use a given
>   application. **The server considers a
>   user licensed** if the user is recorded
>   to have purchased the application, or
>   **if the application is available for
>   free**. To properly identify the user
>   and determine the license status, the
>   server requires information about the
>   application and user — the application
>   and the Android Market client work
>   together to assemble the information
>   and pass it to the server.

and below:

> Requirements and limitations
>
> **Licensing is currently for paid apps
>   only, since free apps are considered
>   licensed for all users**. If your
>   application is already published as
>   free, you won't be able to upload a
>   new version that uses licensing.

Answer (score 0):

More and more apps supporting an in-app payment system (micropayment, donations, paywalls, other payment types as a service (Checkout's restriction to some major credit cards). So some apps are not free, they just have another payment system - and no Licensing support...

**"...since free apps are considered licensed for all users."** matches only for market apps paid using CheckOut.